# Prob when rotating an uiimageview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, rotation

When I am working with uiimageview, I want to rotate it with a small angle, and I did. But, in the border of uiimageview after rotating appears spikes, like a saw. I do not know why and try to fix it but I cant. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your image or something so that we can get an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options..

1) If you are using Core Graphics functions to rotate you can enable anti alias options

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
```

2) Add a 1 pixel transparent border to the your image on all 4 sides.

One more thing, there is a technical term to the spikes you saw and it is aliasing. And the techniques to prevent aliasing are called anti aliasing techniques. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kent don't forget to accept answers that helped you - that's how StackOverflow works and helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all you guys :) My friend showed me another way to fix it. I think this way is better than using transparent border trick. He changed an attribute in info plist file, that is "Renders with edge antialisasing", to YES. And everything becomes okay :). I hope it will help someone get a same prob with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a UIView as subView and Place UIImageView on subView.
Keep the size of subView and UIImageView Same.

Now, Use "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight" or "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft" with Timer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do easily is to add a 1px transparent border around your image. So if your image is, let's say, `50x50` pixels you need to make it `52x52` such that the outer pixels are transparent. When you will rotate it should look fine now.